# Incrementing a for loop, inside the loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, increment

Is it possible to increment a for loop inside of the loop in python 3?

for example:

```
for i in range(0, len(foo_list)):
    if foo_list[i] < bar
        i += 4
```

Where the loop counter `i` gets incremented by 4 if the condition holds true, else it will just increment by one (or whatever the step value is for the for loop)?

I know a while loop would be more applicable for an application like this, but it would be good to know if this (or something like this) in a for loop is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: this might be an x y problem: im not sure why you wouldnt just process your list better before you iterate over it. also look at this: `for i,item_in_list in enumerate(foo_list): print(i,item_in_list)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a while loop and increment `i` based on the condition:

```
while i < (len(foo_list)): 
    if foo_list[i] < bar: # if condition is True increment by 4
        i += 4
    else: 
        i += 1 # else just increment 1 by one and check next `foo_list[i]`
```

Using a for loop `i` will always return to the next value in the range:

```
foo_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
bar = 6
for i in range(len(foo_list)):
    print("range i ",i)
    if foo_list[i] < bar:
        i += 4
        print("if i",i)


('range i ', 0)
('if i', 4)
('range i ', 1)
('if i', 5)
('range i ', 2)
('if i', 6)
('range i ', 3)
('if i', 7)
('range i ', 4)
('if i', 8)
('range i ', 5)
```

Comment: I know my example code doesn't work the way it's supposed to. I was trying to illustrate what I meant by incrementing the loop by more than 1. Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 2):

a bit hackish...

```
>>> b = iter(range(10))
>>> for i in b:
...     print(i)
...     if i==5 : i = next(b)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
>>>
```

Comment: This can be used to replace a while loop with a for loop

Answer (score 1):

In your example as written `i` will be reset at each new iteration of the loop (which may seem a little counterintuitive), as seen here:

```
foo_list = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(foo_list)):
    print('Before increment:', i)
    i += 4
    print('After increment', i)

>>>
Before increment: 0
After increment 4
Before increment: 1
After increment 5
Before increment: 2
After increment 6
```

`continue` is the standard/safe way to skip to the next *single* iteration of a loop, but it would be far more awkward to chain `continues` together than to just use a `while` loop as others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this with a `for` loop using the [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) method of a generator, where the counter can be modified if the generator is sent a new value:

```
def jumpable_range(end):
    counter = 0
    while counter < end:
        jump = yield counter
        if jump is None:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = jump

foo_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
bar = 6
iterable = jumpable_range(len(foo_list))
for i in iterable:
    if foo_list[i] < bar:
        i = iterable.send(i + 4)
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
4
5
6
7
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ImpossibleAcrobaticComputergraphics

Answer (score 0):

```
while i < end:
  # do stuff
  # maybe i +=1
  # or maybe i += 4
```

I suppose you could do this in a for loop if you tried, but it's not advisable. The whole point of python's for loop is to look at items, not indices